# Is it safe to use a local Redis server for caching database queries on production for a low-traffic site?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I will be shipping a site I created to production. The site is a small portfolio, **not expected to have heavy traffic** (if I had 50 concurrent users, I'd be very surprised). It is planned to use the 10-dollar DigitalOcean droplet (1GM RAM, 1 vCPU, 30 GB SSD, 2 TB transfer).

The database queries I make on the platform **are cached**. For development, I'm using local Redis server (running in the Homestead environment).

The official Laravel documentation states:

> The default [Redis] server configuration should suffice for development.
>   However, you are free to modify this array based on your environment.

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

In the case of my site, we're talking about around **15 lightweight queries** in total, so the question is: Is it OK for me to have a local Redis server running on production as well or would you rather suggest employing an external service for that?

Honestly, I would really not like to spend money for a service to cache 15 queries, but I'm interested in good practices, so let's have it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to have local Redis server. You need a remote server only if you have heavy load on your site, or when you have balancer with many app instances and they need to interact with unified redis.

Don't do oprimization while you not have problems.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely reassures me in my approach. However, I've also hard an opposite opinion: *Optimize ahead, so you don't have problems later* ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For caching purposes, it should be ok if you have a redis installed locally. Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil.

Just make sure you don't accidentally bind redis to all interfaces. Also, if you do need to do it, make sure you have good iptables rules implemented on your instance.